# What's the easiest way to return a token from a controller action while carrying on a long-running process?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multithreading, queue

I've got this long-running process in an asp.net MVC3 controller that's functioning as a RESTful service. What I'd like to do is generate a token the caller can use to check on the status of this request, return it to the caller and then go about my biz.

What mechanism is safest, easiest and best for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.3

Use the 202 Accepted response code and return a URL to a status monitor resource.